# python : module attributes missing in python script but not in interpreter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have installed a python package `plivo` using the `sudo pip install plivo`.

and interpreter I test it with some code like:

```
 >>> import plivo
 >>> p = plivo.RestAPI('xxx', 'yyy')
```

everything working fine in python interpreter.

Exactly same code is not working in a python script **test_plivio.py**
giving error : `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RestAPI'`

then I checked with `dir()`
in interpreter

```
>>> dir(plivo)
['Account', 'Application', 'Call', 'Carrier', 'Conference', 'ConferenceMember', 'EndPoint', 'Message', 'Number', 'PLIVO_VERSION', 'PlivoError', 'PlivoResponse', 'Pricing', 'Recording', 'RestAPI', 'SubAccount', 'XML', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'base64', 'hmac', 'json', 'requests', 'sha1', 'validate_signature']
```

`RestAPI` is there.

while in **test_plivo.py** dir(plivo) is like:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'main']
```

clearly `dir(plivo)` in script is missing `RestAPI` with other functions.

Why is that behavior and how to resolve that ?

Comment: Also, if you are using `virtualenv`, `sudo pip install ...` will install into your global python, not into your virtualenv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing a different module; on your path you have a *different* `plivo.py` (or `plivo.pyc` cached bytecode) file.

Print out the `__file__` attribute to see what is imported instead:

```
print plivo.__file__
```

and rename that or move it somewhere else.

Comment: i made a mistake to keep the name of script as plivo.py. Although i remaned it test_plivo.py there was a plivo.pyc and my import was importing that file. thanks

Comment: @naveenyadav: Indeed, a cached bytecode file would also mask another module.